# How to extract hidden tags created by javascript from source page by python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

I have [THIST](http://punkspider.hyperiongray.com/#searchkey=url&searchvalue=search&pagenumber=1&filterType=or&filters=bsqli,sqli,xss,trav,mxi,osci,xpathi) page that has some javascript in it. You can see them by clicking on `show details`.

So how can I extract these data from that url source?

Using `re`?  What I tried in re is:

```
import urllib
import re
gdoc = urllib.urlopen('ThatURL').read()
scriptlis = re.findall('(?si)<script>(.*?)</script>', gdoc)
print scriptlis
```

But no response...

Using selenium?
In this is case how?

```
import lxml
out=lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.parse('ThatURL'))
.
.
.
?
```

Answer (score 2):

When pages use scripting to generate content, it becomes hard to scrape. Instead of plain html reading, you need a full virtual environment capable of executing the script on the document.

For python, there's [`ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). It's pretty flexible, and will allow you to inspect the fully rendered website, as well as to execute your own javascript to interact with the page.

`ghost.py` is a python clone of [`phantom.js`](http://phantomjs.org/), a `node` library. This second tool is superior, in my opinion, but it's not written for python.

Comment: Thank you... How should I use it in this thread to extract that data?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
re.findall('<script.*>.*</script>',url_file)
```